# What are the complete list of punctuation keys for accelerators (keyboard shortcuts)?

Tags: electron

The Electron API docs on [accelerators](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/accelerator) contains the following in the list of available key codes:

> - Punctuations like `~`, `!`, `@`, `#`, `$`, etc.

What is the full list of available key codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This file](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/6-0-x/atom/common/keyboard_util.cc) might give some answers.